# Centos 7, 400x slower for System.nanoTime than windows

Tags: java, jvm, nanotime

I have seen and read posts on why System.nanoTime() is slower on some OSes than others, however I have never seen anything to explain the difference I am seeing now. Using JMH, I am running this benchmark. (Note: it uses System.nanoTime() as well)

```
@Benchmark
public long systemNanoTime() {
    return System.nanoTime();
}
```

On Windows 10, this takes ~25 ns.

On Centos 7, Linux 3.10 it is measured as taking ~10293 ns.

This is on the same machine, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820X CPU @ 3.60GHz

Is there an option to change the way the JDK gets the system clock?

---

EDIT: Based on the link provided by Todd, it appear that tsc is not available

```
# more /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/*
::::::::::::::
/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/available_clocksource
::::::::::::::
hpet acpi_pm 
::::::::::::::
/sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
::::::::::::::
hpet
```

after performing

```
echo acpi_pm > /sys/devices/system/clocksource/clocksource0/current_clocksource
```

The latency improved, but is still poor with a latency of 1,816 ns.

I have tried to find out if the TSC clock source can be added to Centos, but not luck yet.

---

EDIT: Digging a little further

```
# dmesg | grep -i tsc
[    0.000000] tsc: Detected 3600.000 MHz processor
[    0.058602] TSC deadline timer enabled
[    0.065868] TSC synchronization [CPU#0 -> CPU#1]:
[    0.065870] Measured 679995254538 cycles TSC warp between CPUs, turning off TSC clock.
[    0.065874] tsc: Marking TSC unstable due to check_tsc_sync_source failed
[  125.451480] Override clocksource tsc is not HRT compatible. Cannot switch while in HRT/NOHZ mode
```

Comment: Have you checked out this blog post? It describes some of what you see and seems well researched. http://pzemtsov.github.io/2017/07/23/the-slow-currenttimemillis.html

Comment: Seems like a firmware bug. I think I saw tsc synchronization patches in newer kernels (like 4.10).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @apangin's suggestion I followed this page on adding the alternative repository for centos with the latest version

http://elrepo.org/tiki/tiki-index.php

and then followed the further instructions here

https://www.tecmint.com/install-upgrade-kernel-version-in-centos-7/

after installing and rebooting

```
# $ dmesg | grep -i tsc
[    0.001000] tsc: Detected 3600.000 MHz processor
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST: CPU0: -2100392876408 force to 0
[    0.046075] TSC deadline timer enabled
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU1: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU2: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU3: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU4: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU5: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU6: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU7: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU8: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU9: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU10: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU11: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU12: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU13: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU14: 0
[    0.001000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs: Reference CPU0: -2100392876408 CPU15: 0
[    1.337843] clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x6c1bafbc2ab, max_idle_ns: 881591058496 ns
[    2.353636] clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc
```

suggesting the kernel is adjusting for a firmware bug.

Running the test again, I get an average latency of 40 ns using System.nanoTime() which is a 260 fold improvement.  It also means that benchmarks using this measure are more meaningful.