# async profiler displays wrong stacktraces

Tags: java, jvm, async-profiler

I am trying to use [async profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) v.1.8.1 for profiling my application.

JVM is openjdk version "15-ea" 2020-09-15, but same happened with openjdk 14.0.1 as well.

async profiler is run with flags: -d 60 -t -i 10000 -o svg

It shows extremely strange results. [image] We can see that hardware thread spends most of the time not in java.lang.Thread::run, but in some weird place. How can it be explained? I see a possible explanation that async profiler fails to properly traverse stack traces and puts part of these stack traces in a wrong place. Is there another explanation? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Alhough the question lacks a reproducible example (please add it if possible), the main point of the question is understood and makes sense. I think it does not deserve downvotes / close votes.

Comment: Do you run Java in a virtualized environment, in a container, or on the real hardware? What is the kernel version?

Comment: Yes, it is a Ubuntu VM in AWS EC2. I've just updated the kernel to 5.8.0-050800-generic (as advised in your link), but after the reboot the problem remains. I will dig further. Anyway, it already has nothing to do with async profiler per se.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help! It turned out that default clock source was xen. Changing it to tsc has fixed the issue. I used this instruction, in case someone needs it. https://aws.amazon.com/ru/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/manage-ec2-linux-clock-source/

Answer (score 3):

I assume you wonder why there are no Java frames underneath `clock_gettime` in the profile.

As you can see, the stack ends with `[unknown_Java]` frame. This means, the thread indeed runs some Java code, but async-profiler cannot get Java stack trace, because the JVM fails to find the top Java frame.

This happens because `System.nanoTime()` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` are JVM intrinsics. They are JIT-compiled as a direct call of a corresponding C function without switching thread from `in_java` to `in_native` state. This means, the JVM does not save a pointer to the last Java frame when calling `nanoTime` or `currentTimeMillis`, and thus has problems discovering the last Java frame during asynchronous stack walking.

Unfortunately, async-profiler cannot do much about it. One possible workaround is to disable the corresponding JVM intrinsics:

```
java -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:DisableIntrinsic=_currentTimeMillis,_nanoTime
```

BTW, what I find strange in your flame graph is that `clock_gettime` calls into the kernel. Typically it should not, since `clock_gettime` is implemented in [vDSO](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/vdso.7.html) which is mapped into the process' user space. The reason could be a wrong clock source / disabled vDSO ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803565/centos-7-400x-slower-for-system-nanotime-than-windows), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48027025/high-system-cpu-usage-because-of-system-currenttimemillis)).

Comment: Thank you Andrei! Disabling these intrinsics really helped to make profile look reasonable.